# Threads created from Web Application are not killed on redeployment

Tags: java, multithreading, web-applications

I have seen that `Thread` created from a web application is not get killed on redeploying the war file. for the sake of testing I have created a `ServletContextListener` and from the method of `contextInitialized` I created a `Thread`. Which is still running if I remove the code which generated the `Thread` and redeploy the war.

```
import javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent;
import javax.servlet.ServletContextListener;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebListener;

@WebListener
public class RpiServletContextListener implements ServletContextListener {

    public RpiServletContextListener() {

    }

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
        new Thread(() -> {
            while(true) {
                System.out.println("Here------------------");
                try {
                    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(30);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent event) {

    }
}
```

- What is the reason?
- How can I kill it when the application stop?

Environment: Jetty

Answer (score 0):

You can have a flag to mark stop and refer it in your while loop.

```
@WebListener
public class RpiServletContextListener implements ServletContextListener {


    private final AtomicInteger stop = new AtomicInteger(1);

    public RpiServletContextListener() {

    }

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
        new Thread(() -> {
            while(stop.get() <= 1) {
                System.out.println("Here------------------");
                try {
                    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(30);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent event) {
        this.stop.incrementAndGet();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. But why the threads are not get killed?

Comment: @TapasBose Because you havn't written any code to do so, and there's nothing in the servlet container that would kill them either. You're supposed to manage your stuff, including threads you create.